# VBA How to reference an active file with a variable filename

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I have to import data from an export excel file `(export (1).xlsx`) into my base file `(Productlist.xlsx`).
So this online application produces a file called `export (1).xlsx`
We don't store this export file, we just hit the import button in `"Productlist.xlsx"`, the data gets imported onto sheet 4, and then we close our `"export (1).xlsx"`.

The code works as long as the filename is exactly `"export (1).xlsx"`.
But when I do a second export the filename gets altered to 
`"export (2) (1).xlsx"` 
One solution is to close the application and start over, but this is frustrating...

I'm looking for a way to refer to this export file using a wildcard to replace the variable part in the file name...
e.g. 
    `Application.Goto Workbooks("Export *.XLSX").Sheets(1).Range("A2:AX500")`

I've seen threads to look for a file in a stored directory using a wildcard, but none so far to refer to active workbooks...

Here's my code:

```
Sub ImportOvWeb()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim PasteStart As Range
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set PasteStart = Sheets(4).Range("A2")

    wb1.Sheets(4).Unprotect

    ' Delete all entrees from previous import

    Application.Goto (wb1.Sheets(4).Range("A2:AX500"))
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2").Select

    ' Import data from 'export.xlsm'

    Application.Goto Workbooks("Export (1).XLSX"").Sheets(1).Range("A2:AX500")
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto PasteStart
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A2").Select   

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA recognizing workbook by partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358293/vba-recognizing-workbook-by-partial-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function to loop through open workbooks looking for one named like "*export*":

```
Sub ImportOvWeb()

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim shtPaste As Worksheet
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String

    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shtPaste = wbDest.Sheets(4)

    shtPaste.Unprotect
    shtPaste.Range("A2:AX500").ClearContents

    Set wbSrc = FindByName("export") '<< find a matching workbook
    If Not wbSrc Is Nothing Then
       'got a match  - copy the data
        wbSrc.Sheets(1).Range("A2:AX500").Copy shtPaste.Range("A2")
    Else  
        MsgBox "Export workbook not found!" 
    End if

End Sub

'Find the first workbook with a name containing "nm"
'Returns Nothing if no match
Function FindByName(nm As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb 
    For Each wb in Workbooks
        If wb.name like "*" & nm & "*" Then
            Set FindByName = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I would do it, I've cleaned your code from variables you didn't use and redundant lines:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportOvWeb()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Delete all entrees from previous import
    With wb1.Sheets(4)
        .Unprotect
        .Range("A2:AX500").ClearContents
    End With

    'look for the file
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        'if any of the workbooks is called export will set it to the wb2 variable
        If wb.Name Like "*export*" Then
            Set wb2 = wb
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "there is no export file openned. Please try again."
            End
        End If
    Next wb

    ' Import data from 'export.xlsm'
    wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:AX500").Copy wb1.Sheets(4).Range("A2")

End Sub
```