# I have an excel workbook with multiple tabs and want to select a tab using vba that has a date that changes each week

Tags: excel, vba

I download an excel sheet each week and the name of the tab has today's date in it which obviously changes each week. I add other excel exports to the same workbook so I have 3 different tabs, one of them being the tab with the current date. How can I set up my vba macro to select the tab each week in an excel workbook, even with the date changing? Can I use a wildcard?

[Here is an image of the tabs. You can see that the first tab has a date. Only the date changes each week but the first part stays the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpEb2.png)

Comment: Loop over the tabs and find the one with name beginning with "Task Start Date"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358293/vba-recognizing-workbook-by-partial-name

Comment: Adding to @TimWilliams comment; per your example, if your worksheet `is always the first worksheet(tab)`, you can use the `worksheet Index number`, e.g. `Sheets(1)` without using a wildcard or name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
Sub whatever()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
For Each mySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If mySheet.Name Like "Sheet*" Then
        mySheet.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next mySheet
End Sub
```

I tested this on the workbook below. "other stuff" was selected to begin. Then it found "Sheet123456789"

[image]

Comment: Hi @ari_gasparoni , you are very welcome. Please click to accept the answer as the solution if you don't mind. Have a great day =)