# VBA Excel Set Workbook with name like something

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation, in which my code needs to be referred to the external workbook, which has been created just recently. Therefore it doesn't have a generic name. Because the name is default it always comes as Book1, Book2, Book3, etc.

I found a nice hint here:

[VBA recognizing workbook by partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358293/vba-recognizing-workbook-by-partial-name)

And applied to my situation like below:

```
 Dim mwkt As Workbook, pwkt As Workbook
 Dim wbName As String
 wbName = "Book"
 For Each pwkt In Application.Workbooks
 If pwkt.Name Like wbName & "*" Then
 Set pwkt = pwkt.Name
 End If
 Next pwkt

  Set pwkt = pwkt.Name  retiurns the **'Type mismatch'** error.
```

Is there any way of sirting this out?

Comment: You should set (reference) the workbook right after it was created. Please add the lines that do so to your post. Doing it your way is too risky and might fail if there are any random never-saved workbooks open. Why take a chance?

Comment: You are right I agree, but where should I set the reference to this workbook? Do you mean that the entire code should be moved towards the beginning and place just below the 
NewWorkbook.Add?

Comment: No, just use `Dim pwkt As Workbook: Set pwkt = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)`. Or, to export a worksheet to a new workbook, use e.g. `ws.Copy: Set pwkt = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`.

Comment: Add an `Exit For` line immediately after the `Set` line, since you can stop looping at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'pwkt.Name' will return a String but you have declared pwkt as a Workbook. That is the type mismatch.

You are also using the variable pwkt for the loop and also for the setting within the loop. Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
Dim mwkt As Workbook, pwkt As Workbook, wb as Workbook
Dim wbName As String
wbName = "Book"
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like wbName & "*" Then
        Set pwkt = wb
    End If
Next wb
```